# WSO2 Invalid Request Line: GET /

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB version 6.1.1 and I have a problem with handling all HTTP requests.
In our company we are using F5 ASM and every second F5 module sends requests to wso2 server's http and https ports. So, wso2 gives error because any service doesn't match with this request. And I can not create an Api or Proxy for "http://WSO2_URL/8280/" or "https://WSO2_URL/8243"

Because of them, my log file contains a lot of error lines. I should get away from this error.

Can anybody suggest me a solution about this?

`TID: [-1] [] [2019-01-29 10:32:52,947]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  Writer null when calling informWriterError {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-01-29 10:32:54,274] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  HttpException occurred  {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler}
org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid request line: GET /
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:208)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection$LoggingNHttpMessageParser.parse(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:407)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection$LoggingNHttpMessageParser.parse(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:381)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpServerConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpServerConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpServerConnection.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onInputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:82)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerIODispatch.onInputReady(ServerIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:113)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ParseException: Invalid request line: GET /
        at org.apache.http.message.BasicLineParser.parseRequestLine(BasicLineParser.java:298)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpRequestParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.DefaultHttpRequestParser.createMessage(DefaultHttpRequestParser.java:51)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeadLine(AbstractMessageParser.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:206)
        ... 14 more`

Comment: To send a request on a specific port, you have to put " : " after your domain name, instead of "/". `https://WSO2URL:8243/<your ressource path>`

Comment: But I need handler for "/" path. I don't have any problem with resource paths.

Comment: Ask your network team to create a custom health check for https://WSO2_URL:8443.